# C# / EF Core: How can the performance of this code / queries be improved?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, query-optimization

I am trying to implement a auto-trading bot and want to backtest its performance on historical market data.
This function mocks the real one and presents the "current" prices:

```
public DateTime Current = new DateTime(2022, 08, 05, 8, 0, 0);
public async Task<List<Quote>> GetLatestQuotes(List<string> isins)
{
    using var context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
    List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote>();
    foreach (var isin in isins)
    {
        var stockPrice = context.HistoricalMinutePrices.Where(x => x.Stock.Isin == isin && x.Time <= Current).OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).FirstOrDefault();
        if (stockPrice is null)
            continue;
        var quote = new Quote { Time = stockPrice.Time, Ask = stockPrice.Ask, Bid = stockPrice.Bid, Isin = isin };
        quotes.Add(quote);   
    }
    Current = Current.AddMinutes(1);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{Current:g}]");
    return quotes;
}
```

It gets the "latest" price entry for each stock in the database. "Latest" refers to the DateTime that moves by 1 minute each iteration.

Now the problem is, that I use a SQLite DB and it contains a lot of entries even for only a day of data: 100 stocks * 60 minutes * 24 hours = 144.000 entries a day. I think the OrderBy takes a lot of performance and the fact that it fires 100 single sqls.
How this can be improved?

The Database is available local on the machine

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators)

The you can use Window Functions:

```cs
public async Task<List<Quote>> GetLatestQuotes(List<string> isins)
{
    using var context = _factory.CreateDbContext();

    var query = context.HistoricalMinutePrices
        .Where(x => isins.Contains(x.Stock.Isin) && x.Time <= Current)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
                .PartitionBy(x.Stock.Isin)
                .OrderByDesc(x.Time)
                .ToValue(),
            Record = x
        })
        .Where(x => x.RN == 1)
        .Select(x => x.Record);
    
    var quotes = await query.ToListAsyncLinqToDB();

    Current = Current.AddMinutes(1);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{Current:g}]");
    return quotes;
}
```

Also ensure that you have index on column `Time`

Comment: Unfortunately this is even slower, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you accept third party extensions? Also, which indexes are available on your table?

Comment: I have no problem in third party stuff as long as it runs on arm / 32 bit.
Stocks have an Id and Isin with Id being the primary key.
HistoricalMinutePrices also have an Id as primary key and a foreign key to stocks.
A index from the HistoricalMinutePrices.StockId to Stock.Id and a unique index on Stocks.Isin,

I have posted my own solution as an answer to this question. It is sufficiently fast now, but feel free to further improve it. I modified it a bit using a dictionary instead of list for the hourly split data because the string comparison took quite long.

Comment: I tried this and ran into another problem. My HistoricalMinutePrice class is actually empty but derives from a Stockprice. Now LinqToDb can't find the index from HistoricalMinutePrice to the StockId: LinqException: Association key 'StockId' not found for type 'AutoTrading.Database.Stockprice.
It is present in the DB tho: CREATE INDEX "IX_HistoricalMinutePrices_StockId" ON "HistoricalMinutePrices" ("StockId")

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works quite well for now:

```
public DateTime Current = new DateTime(2022, 08, 05, 8, 0, 0);
private List<Quote> _quotesInDay;
private List<Quote> _quotesInHour;
public async Task<List<Quote>> GetLatestQuotes(List<string> isins)
{
    if (Current.Hour == 22)
        Current = Current.AddHours(10);
    if (_quotesInDay is null || _quotesInDay.First().Time.Day != Current.Day)
    {
        using var context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        _quotesInHour = null;
        _quotesInDay = context.HistoricalMinutePrices.Where(x => x.Time.Day == Current.Day).Select(x => new Quote { Time = x.Time, Ask = x.Ask, Bid = x.Bid, Isin = x.Stock.Isin }).ToList();
    }
    if (_quotesInHour is null || _quotesInHour.First().Time.Hour != Current.Hour)
        _quotesInHour = _quotesInDay.Where(x => x.Time >= Current.AddMinutes(-10) && x.Time < Current.AddMinutes(60)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).ToList();

    List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote>();
    foreach (var isin in isins)
    {
        var quote = _quotesInHour.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Isin == isin && x.Time <= Current);
        if (quote is null)
            continue;
        quotes.Add(quote);
    }
    Current = Current.AddMinutes(1);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{Current:g}]");
    return quotes;
}
```

I load the whole data for one day at the beginning of each day in memory at once.
Then I chunk this data into groups of one hour. This hourly data is sorted only once by time.

This way only one sql is fired for each day (compared to ~100k before) and way less sorting happens.